# WinForm application always comes in foreground when any file/folder/application is opened after pressing windows + D

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a WinForm app developed in VC++.
The minimize option for the main form of the application is been disabled.
When I press Windows + D (to see Desktop), the application goes on to taskbar.

But after this, if I open any other window (any other file/folder/other application/even sticky notes), my application comes in foreground.
I do not want this to happen. I want my application to remain on taskbar.

Can any one help me, why this is happening?
How this issue can be resolved?

Comment: Why do you have a c# tag?

Comment: When you say "application comes in foreground", does this mean that it will appear on top of the other window that you opened?

Comment: @YacoubMassad: By mistake the C# tag got added..

Comment: Is it by any chance, that the dialog have a WS_EX_TOPMOST, or any high modality?

Comment: @YacoubMassad: Yes, it appears on top of other window.

Comment: @ntohl: There is no such property is been set in application. As per my knowledge, modality is not set for the application. How to find high modality of application?

Comment: I found something like that. But You have to flex it together. `[DllImport("User32.Dll")]                
public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);` for the SetWindowLong, and `SetWindowLong(pMainWindow, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_the extended window prop You want);`. I'm not familiar with VC++.